# Joomla 2.5 - Rollback on model method save()

Tags: php, joomla2.5

This is what I'm trying to do:

I save my item in the model, then I call a method that can throw an exception if something goes wrong.

If I catch the exception, I want to rollback, this is my override of the save method:

```
public function save($data) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->transactionStart();
    $retVal = parent::save($data);
    if ($retVal) {
        try {
            $this->_doSomething();
            $db->transactionCommit();
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            $db->transactionRollback();
            JFactory::getApplication('administrator')
            ->enqueueMessage($exc->getMessage(), 'error');
            return false;// THIS MAKES ROLLBACK FAIL, TO MAKE IT WORK I HAVE TO COMMENT THIS.
        }
    }
    return $retVal;
}
```

It only works if my method returns `true` anyway.

To me it should be more correct that the method in this case returns `false`, because the saving is **not** done and because if it returns `true`, Joomla outputs a misleading message as if saving succeded.
But if it does rollback somehow it fails.

What makes rollback fail if the method `save()` returns `false`?